# How do I use a specific date/time in Splunk dashboard with earliest and latest?

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

How do I use a specific date/time in Splunk dashboard with earliest and latest? I cannot figure out the syntax to have a Splunk dashboard take a hard-coded **exact** date rather than an offset.

This works perfectly well; from 2 day ago to 1 days ago, a 24 hour span:

```
<earliest>-2d@h</earliest>
<latest>-1d@h</latest>
```

I referred to this documentation: [https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.1/Search/Specifytimemodifiersinyoursearch#:~:text=For%20exact%20time%20ranges%2C%20the,April%2027%2C%202022](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.1/Search/Specifytimemodifiersinyoursearch#:%7E:text=For%20exact%20time%20ranges%2C%20the,April%2027%2C%202022).
and their example for search bar is:

```
earliest=04/19/2022:00:00:00 latest=04/27/2022:00:00:00
```

However, trying to apply that to my dashboard, the below gives me:  `Invalid earliest_time.`

```
<earliest>11/13/2023:00:00:00</earliest>
<latest>11/14/2023:00:00:00</latest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited docs are for specifying `earliest` and `latest` in SPL, but that's not what's happening here.  This is a Simple XML dashboard with different rules.  Simple XML requires `earliest` and `latest` to be either a relative time or a Unix epoch.  See "Child Elements" at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.2/Viz/PanelreferenceforSimplifiedXML#search

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. Afterwards, I built dashboards using epoch times for some specific timeframes. As a result, I was able to track down a major performance regression, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a time picker, and then select from *it* the earliest and latest in your search

Say you name your time picker `timetok`

The search would look like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp earliest=$timetok.earliest$ latest=$timetok.latest$ ...
```